# How to combine time series which have differing release dates every week or month?

Tags: time-series

Here a few cases I run into while building a time-series model.

**Case 1: Two time series, both monthly, different release dates.**

Say I want to take the quotient of monthly time series **A** which is released on the 15th of each month and time series **B** which is released on the 1st of each month, then take the 3 month and 12 month moving averages of this quotient. Do I:

1. resample to daily, forward fill, take the quotien, then compute MA windows with 21 * 3 days and 260 days
2. shift the older time series so that instead of "being released" on day 1 of the month, my model assumes it is released on the 15th of the month, then take the quotien, then compute MA windows with 3 months and 12 months
3. something else?

**Case 2: Two time series, one weekly + one monthly, (obviously) different release dates.**

Similar to case 1, I want to take the quotient between the two time series and then compute moving averages. How should I go about it this time?

**Discussion**

I tried looking, but couldn't find answers to this kind of offset date questions. My biggest issue is I don't want to introduce any lookahead bias in my model, while also trying to remain as close as possible to the business logic (in Case 1, I want the MA to be sensitive to the changes from month to month and not slowed down by the daily forward fills).

Thank you in advance for any and all help with this subject!